# Calculate time difference depending on another column (Power BI)

Tags: python, powerbi, dax

I want to calculate time difference. I have a timestamp on each row, that is either incoming or outgoing.
e.g.

| Msg | Timestamp | StateAfter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:02 | 1 |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:03 | 1 |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:05 | 1 |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:06 | 0 |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:08 | 0 |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:09 | 1 |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:10 | 1 |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:11 | 0 |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:12 | 0 |

i tried to solve the problem with index. However Msg's don't always happen on top of each other (incoming and outgoing).
(StateAfter column --> 0: outgoing, 1: incoming).

| Msg | Timestamp | StateAfter | Calculated Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:02 | 1 |  |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:03 | 1 |  |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:05 | 1 |  |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:06 | 0 | 00:00:04 |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:08 | 0 | 00:00:05 |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:09 | 1 |  |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:10 | 1 |  |
| A | 01.01.2019 11:02:11 | 1 | 00:00:02 |
| B | 01.01.2019 11:02:12 | 1 | 00:00:02 |

Result should be

| Msg | total-time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 00:00:06 |
| B | 00:00:07 |

thank you a lot

Comment: can you explain further what this means "*Msg's don't always happen on top of each other (incoming and outgoing)*" and what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: This can be done in Power Query (Transform) using custom aggregations in Table.Group

Comment: @D.L sorry my englisch. I meant following. we want to calculate the duration of Messages (Msg.). They are labeled with oncomming our outgoing. For example you get a Message A at time X. This message can be labeled oncomming again if this confirming on a panel. Meanwhile, more news will come. Eventually message A will disapper (outgoing) at time Y. I would like to calculate the duration of this onhold time of Message A. In this case Duration = Y-X. Incomming and outgoing information can you get on column "SaateAfter".

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it sounds good. I try with it. Thank you for your advice

Comment: unfortunately i can not solve this issue. if I create a group then i have to run following function like sum, avarage etc. But I would like to calculate the difftime. May be can you give me a further hint.

Comment: hi again, nearly i got it. i grouped whole messages and i can see the related time on same row. i can see on my table the stateafter too. But i cannot calculate rows. is there any way to compute time difference according to value on other column.